# report on content custom field

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, content, document, contentdocument

is there a way to report on custom fields of content attached/related to an account?

Scenario: I have multiple record type for Salesforce Files. When uploading document to Library I can chose the record type and enter some values into fields associated to the page layout of the record type.
Once I have saved the document to the library, I then go to an account and attach the content using the "find related content".

Challenge: how can I report on the files uploaded and show the account id to which the file is attached and also show the value of the custom fields filled in?